# I keep getting the error message " AttributeError: type object 'Pipe' has no attribute 'moving_x' " when I run my game

Tags: python

my class file contains

```
def __init__(self, xpos):

    self.fixed_y = random.randint(150, 650)
    self.moving_x = xpos

    self.bot_surf = pygame.image.load("graphics/pipe.png").convert_alpha()
    self.top_surf = pygame.transform.flip(self.bot_surf, False, True)
```

and i get the error even though i thought i was clearly referring to the correct object

```
if bird_rect.centerx == Obstacle.Pipe.moving_x:
    score_surf = font.render(str(int(score)), False, ("#FFFFFF"))
    score += 1
screen.blit(score_surf, (550, 100))
```

Comment: How do you create `Obstacle.Pipe`?

Comment: Please provide your entire .py source file, make it as short as possible. Also, please provide the full error message, with stack trace.